# How to draw weekly-open line on a different resolution via line.new()

Tags: pine-script

The aim is to plot a horizontal (trend-line) at weekly open price, on 1H chart. The line's x1 coordinate should start from the 1H bar where current weekly candle opened. But not sure how to get the correct bar-shift on 1H chart.

```
//@version=4
study("Test--vX02", overlay=true)
wOpen= security(syminfo.tickerid,"W",open)         
line1 = line.new(x1=/*confused*/, y1= wOpen, x2=/*confused*/, y2=wOpen, style=line.style_solid, color=color.green)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work.

```
//@version=4
study("Test--vX02", overlay=true)

var line1 = line.new(na, na, na, na, style=line.style_solid, color=color.green, extend=extend.right)

if change(weekofyear)
    line.set_xy1(line1, bar_index[1], open)
    line.set_xy2(line1, bar_index,    open)
```